# Is there an npm for oauth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to make a request to yelp.com from my node server, but I need to use `OAuth.getParameterMap` and other OAuth functions in my request.  I was wondering if there were any npm's with the functions I needed?

This is my code so far:

```
app.post('/yelpApp', function (req, res)
{
    var auth = {
    consumerKey: conKey,
    consumerSecret: conSec,
    accessToken: accTok,
    accessTokenSecret: accTokSec,
    serviceProvider: {
      signatureMethod: "HMAC-SHA1"
      }
    };

    var terms = 'food';
    var near = 'London';
    var accessor = {
      consumerSecret: auth.consumerSecret,
      tokenSecret: auth.accessTokenSecret
    };
    parameters = [];
    parameters.push(['term', terms]);
    parameters.push(['location', near]);
    parameters.push(['callback', 'cb']);
    parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', auth.consumerKey]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_secret', auth.consumerSecret]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_token', auth.accessToken]);
    parameters.push(['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1']);

    var message = {
      'action': 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search',
      'method': 'GET',
      'parameters': parameters
    };

    //can't use these OAuth functions on server
    OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
    OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
    var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
    parameterMap.oauth_signature =  OAuth.percentEncode(parameterMap.oauth_signature)

    $.ajax(
    {
    'url': message.action,
    'data': parameterMap,
    'cache': true,
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': function(data, textStats, XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({foo: data}));
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic for SO. Please take a look at the [help/dont-ask] for a list. Also, I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth) simply by searching on the title of your question: please search before asking. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was just wondering if there was an npm with the the functions I needed. Also you clearly didn't read the rest of my question or what was in that package as there is no `setTimestampAndNonce`, `SignatureMethod`, `getParameterMap`, or `percentEncode` in it.

Comment: You got me, I didn't bother reading an off-topic question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Node-yelp](https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp) provides methods for interfacing with Yelp, including authentication. It depends on [oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth)

Answer (score 1):

[Passport](http://passportjs.org/) handles this. Check it out ;)